# Implement the interface during run time

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to create a API module which has all the necessary function to execute required functions. But only thing that need to be done by the end developer is to implement the class based on whether he choose to use database or filesystem

There is IContentProcess which will be used in AssetManager which does the file processing and other functions. Right now i'm implementing the ContentProcess within the AssetManager class but i really want the end developer who is using my jar file could able to implement so that he can save the files in the database or filesystem.

What i need to do in the AssetManager class to achieve it?

```
public interface IContentProcessor
{

    public boolean deleteContent(String fileName) throws ResourceException;


    public boolean uploadContent(String fileName, InputStream contentStream) throws ResourceException;


    public InputStream downloadContent(String fileName) throws ResourceException;


    public boolean uploadContent(String fileName, BufferedImage imageStream) throws ResourceException;


    public boolean uploadContent(String fileName, String formatName, BufferedImage imageStream)
            throws ResourceException;


    public boolean moveContent(String fromFile, String toFile) throws ResourceException;


    public void validateFilePath(File newFile);
}
```

### AssetManager

```
private IContentProcessor createContentProcessor()
    {
            ........
            return new ContentProcessorNFSImpl();

    }
    ......
        /**
         * Upload the given content.
         * 
         * @return
         */
        private boolean uploadContentStream(String filePath, InputStream contentStream)
        {
            IContentProcessor contentProcessor = createContentProcessor();
            try
            {
                return contentProcessor.uploadContent(filePath, contentStream);
            }
            catch (ResourceException rEx)
            {
                throw new SystemException(rEx.getMessage(), rEx);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**API implemenation**

Provide a setter method to inject implementation

```
public class AssetManager {
   ...
   private IContentProcessor contentProcessor
   ...

   // This method to be invoked by client to set (a.k.a inject) customer implemenation
   public void setContentProcesssor(IContentProcessor c) {
      this.contentProcessor = c;
   }
}
```

And, remove the `IContentProcessor contentProcessor = createContentProcessor();` line from `uploadContentStream` method.

**Developer's (a.k.a API user) code**

Developer is free to implement `IContentProcessor` and inject the implementation using `setContentProcessor` method.  You can provide some pre-built implementation as part of your library, or developer can implement completely new version of `IContentProcessor`

```
AssetManager m = new AssetManager(...);
m.setContentProcessor(new ContentProcessorNFSImpl());
...
m.uploadContentStream(...);
```

Also, instead of creating an instance of `ContentProcessor`, developer can choose to use Spring Framework and auto-wire the implementation in his/her code.

Comment: if by default i set content processor in constructor. Is it still still better way to set the contentProcessor by developer?

Comment: If you have a default implementation, that will work 90% of time, only then it may be okay to do that.  I would prefer developer pick the implementaion always.

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged this with `spring`. You can do this with [Spring dependency injection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-collaborators). Get rid of the `createContentProcessor()` method, and use Spring dependency injection instead. Your class would for example look like this:

```
@Component
public class MyClass {

    // Will be set by Spring dependency injection
    @Autowired
    private IContentProcessor contentProcessor;

    // ...

    private boolean uploadContentStream(String filePath, InputStream contentStream)
    {
        try
        {
            return contentProcessor.uploadContent(filePath, contentStream);
        }
        catch (ResourceException rEx)
        {
            throw new SystemException(rEx.getMessage(), rEx);
        }
    }
}
```

The Spring configuration would then determine what particular implementation of `IContentProcessor` would be used.

If you want to do this without Spring: you can dynamically create an instance of the interface using reflection:

```
private IContentProcessor createContentProcessor() throws ClassNotFoundException,
        IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    // You could get the class name from a config file
    String implClassName = "com.somepackage.ContentProcessorNFSImpl";

    // Load the class and create an instance
    // This requires the implementation to have a public no-args constructor
    return (IContentProcessor) Class.forName(implClassName).newInstance();
}
```

Comment: How to support non-spring way?

Comment: @user1595858 Why did you tag it with `spring` if your question is not related to Spring?

Comment: I'm creating api for spring based application as well as non spring based application.

Comment: Typically, instead of hardcoding `implClassName `, one would fetch it from a properties file or equivalent.